# Problema para enrutar en cakephp

Tags: cakephp, layout, router, href

tengo un pequeño problema, en realidad son dos pero creo que no puedo hacer dos preguntas en esta misma pagina.

Bno estoy creando un boton nuevo, en una pagina, lo copie literalmente de otro y no surte los cambios aqui les muestro los codigos:

Códigos del boton en el que me estoy basando
ConfigController.php

```
public function assesor_index($active_pill = null)
    {
        $this->layout = 'assesor';

        $user = $this->Auth->user();

        $doctor = $user['Doctor'];

        $pendings = $this->AppointmentUser->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array('appointment_state_id' => '1', 'doctor_id' => $user['Doctor']['id']),
            'order' => array('date_created DESC')));
        $appointments = $this->AppointmentUser->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array('appointment_state_id' => '2', 'doctor_id' => $user['Doctor']['id']),
            'order' => array('date_created DESC')));
        $effectives = $this->AppointmentUser->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array('appointment_state_id' => '3', 'doctor_id' => $user['Doctor']['id']),
            'order' => array('date_created DESC')));
        $todoctor = $this->AppointmentUser->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array('appointment_state_id' => '4', 'doctor_id' => $user['Doctor']['id']),
            'order' => array('date_created DESC')));
        $noteffective = $this->AppointmentUser->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array('appointment_state_id' => '5', 'doctor_id' => $user['Doctor']['id']),
            'order' => array('date_created DESC')));

        $this->set(compact('appointments', 'pendings', 'effectives', 'todoctor', 'doctor', 'noteffective', 'active_pill'));
    }
```

Aquí esta ubicado el menu el cual esta en elements y se llama assesor_menu.ctp, el segundo li fue el que yo cree, y me base en el primero para crearlo pero no funciona

```
<li>
        <?php
            echo $this->Html->link('<div><i class="fa fa-user-md fa-fw"></i> Consultas </div>', 
                            array('controller' => 'config', 'action' => 'index', 'assesor' => true), 
                            array('escape' => false));
        ?>
        </li>
           <li>
        <?php
            echo $this->Html->link('<div class="clickPoliticasWeb"><i class="fa fa-user-md fa-fw"></i> Politicas del sitio web</div>', 
                            array('controller' => 'config', 'action' => 'index', 'politics' => true), 
                            array('escape' => false));
        ?>
        </li>
        <li>
                <?php
                    echo $this->Html->link('<i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Salir', 
                            array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout', 'admin' => true), 
                            array('escape' => false)
                    );
                ?>
                </li>
```

Lo raro es que en codigo fuente se ve otra ruta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
La ruta deberia ser politics/config ps la del boton que ya existia es assesor/config

Layouts:
Assesors.ctp y Politics.ctp por ahora tienen lo mismo, pero no me carga el Politics es como si no lo encontrara. La unica diferencia es que a uno de los dos le puse un input text, y si ese input esta en politics no lo muestra, si esta en assesors, ps si lo muestra.

```
<?php



$pageDescription = __d('seadog_base', 'SEADOG Base');
$pageName = __d('seadog_base', 'IQ Administración');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
<head>
    <?php echo $this->Html->charset(); ?>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>
        <?php echo $pageName.' :'; ?>
        <?php echo $title_for_layout; ?>
    </title>

    <?php 
        echo $this->Html->meta('keywords','SEADOG, dessign, creativity, lab, Endor inc');
        echo $this->Html->meta('description', 'Seadog base template');
        echo $this->Html->meta('language', 'es');

        echo $this->Html->meta('favicon.ico', '/img/favicon.ico', array('type' => 'icon')); 

        /* CSS */
        echo $this->Html->css(array(
            'bootstrap.min',
            'metisMenu.min',
            'admin', 
            'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css',
        ));

        /* JS */
        echo $this->Html->script(array(
            'jquery.min',   
             '../ckeditor/ckeditor', '../ckeditor/config', /* ckeditor */ 
        ));
        //this is loaded at the end of the page.
        echo $this->Html->script(array(
            'metisMenu.min',
            'bootstrap.min',
            'admin', 
            ), array('async' => 'async', 'block' => 'scriptBottom') 
        );

        echo $this->fetch('meta');
        echo $this->fetch('css');
        echo $this->fetch('script');
    ?>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <?php echo  $this->element('assesor_menu'); ?>

    <!--nocache-->  
    <!-- display session messaging -->
    <div id="flassMessage" class="container">
        <?php $flashMessage = $this->Session->flash();
            if($flashMessage){
                echo '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">
                                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>';
                echo $flashMessage;
                echo '</div>';  
            }

            $flash_auth = $this->Session->flash('auth'); 
            if($flash_auth){
                echo '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">
                                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>';
                echo $flash_auth;
                echo '</div>';
            }
        ?>
    </div> <!-- end flash -->
    <!--/nocache-->     

    <!-- display page content -->
    <input type="text" name="vlr">
    <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>

</div> <!-- end wrapper -->

<?php echo $this->fetch('scriptBottom'); //header scripts ?>    
<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); // Write cached scripts ?>


</body>
</html>
```

[image: Ubicacion]

Controlador de politics

```
public function politics_index($active_pill = null)
    {
        $this->set(compact());
    }
```

foto cambio 1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Es comos i al intentar entrar a :

```
 <a href="/politics/config"><div><i class="clickPoliticasWeb fa fa-user-md fa-fw"></i> Politicas del sitio web</div></a>        </li>
```

no me dejara

Comment: En tu `core.php` tienes una línea así `Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('assesor'));`?

Comment: `Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin', 'assesor', 'resource', 'contacts'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La razón por la que no funciona es porque no has declarado el prefijo en `core.php`.

El HtmlHelper al no tener ese prefijo en la configuración esta tomando a `'politics' => true` como un parámetro extra y por eso lo agrega al final de la URL.

En tu archivo `core.php` agrega al arreglo de prefijos `politics`

```
Configure::write(
    'Routing.prefixes', 
     array(
         'admin', 
         'assesor', 
         'resource', 
         'contacts', 
         'politics' // Agregamos el prefijo 'politics'
     )
);
```

Comment: Si hay mismo que lo vi lo hice, al darle click ya es como si no tuvieras permisos, subire la foto como respuesta para que veas que me sale

Comment: @AndrésVélez por curiosidad en tu AppController tienes un método que se llama `isAuthorized`?

Comment: `public function isAuthorized($user = null) {
     // All registered users view list
     $user = $this->Auth->user();
     if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'assesor' && !empty($this->request->params['assesor'])) {
          return true;...`

Comment: Me imagino que es por eso, pero creo que iría mejor en una pregunta nueva. Ponla y te ayudo, si no lo hace alguien mas antes :)

Comment: Agregue un if con politis y listo.
Ya llega a la pagina, debería agregarte a fb KacosPro para escribirte para problemas con Cake jajajajajaj sin mentir me has solucionado mas de 15 preguntas de las que he hecho aqui ajajjajaj

Bno escribire la otra pregunta que es hacer un insert a la BD cuando chulee un checkbox,

Comment: Jajajaja no soy muy activo en facebook, pero si quieres me puedes mencionar en un comentario en las preguntas cuando sean de cake.  Oye por cierto vi que no has terminado el [tour], terminalo para que puedas ganar otra medalla :D